# Pandas: Multi-index apply function between column and index

Tags: python, pandas, apply, attributeerror, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe that look like this:

```
In[13]: df
Out[13]:
              Last Trade
Date       Ticker           
1983-03-30 CLM83  1983-05-18
           CLN83  1983-06-17
           CLQ83  1983-07-18
           CLU83  1983-08-19
           CLV83  1983-09-16
           CLX83  1983-10-18
           CLZ83  1983-11-18
1983-04-04 CLM83  1983-05-18
           CLN83  1983-06-17
           CLQ83  1983-07-18
           CLU83  1983-08-19
           CLV83  1983-09-16
           CLX83  1983-10-18
           CLZ83  1983-11-18
```

With two levels for indexes (namely 'Date' and 'Ticker'). I would like to apply a function to the column 'Last Trade' that would let me know how many months separate this 'Last Trade' date from the index 'Date'
I found a function that does the calculation:

```
from calendar import monthrange

def monthdelta(d1, d2):
    delta = 0
    while True:
        mdays = monthrange(d1.year, d1.month)[1]
        d1 += datetime.timedelta(days=mdays)
        if d1 <= d2:
            delta += 1
        else:
            break
    return delta
```

I tried to apply the following function h but it returns me an AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'index':

```
In[14]: h = lambda x: monthdelta(x.index.get_level_values(0),x)

In[15]: df['Last Trade'] = df['Last Trade'].apply(h)
```

How can I apply a function that would use both a column and an index value?

Thank you for your tips,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of your function:

## Option 1

### You get an integer number

```
def monthdelta(row):
    trade = row['Last Trade'].year*12 + row['Last Trade'].month
    date = row['Date'].year*12 + row['Date'].month
    return trade - date

df.reset_index().apply(monthdelta, axis=1)
```

---

Inspired by PiRsquared:

```
df = df.reset_index()
(df['Last Trade'].dt.year*12 + df['Last Trade'].dt.month) -\
(df['Date'].dt.year*12 + df['Date'].dt.month)
```

## Option 2

### You get a [`numpy.timedelta64`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Which can be directly used for other date computations. However, this will be in the form of days, not months, because the number of [days in a month are not constant](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic).

```
def monthdelta(row):
    return row['Last Trade'] - row['Date']

df.reset_index().apply(monthdelta, axis=1)
```

---

Inspired by PiRsquared:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Last Trade'] - df['Date']
```

Option 2 will of course be faster, because it involves less computations. Pick what you like!

---

To get your index back: `df.index = df[['Date', 'Ticker']]`

Comment: Your first solution gives me `AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'", u'occurred at index 0')`  I suspect because the `apply` is feeding row by row and thus `row['Last Trade']` and `row['Date']` are not scalar TimeStamps and no longer series.  Therefore don't need `dt` accessors.

Comment: But `dtypes` should be conserved across `.apply`. What does `df.reset_index().dtypes` indicate?

Comment: Look at the timings I added to my post.  You'll see the code I used for your solutions.  I removed the `.dt` from the the function.  It doesn't work for me otherwise.

Comment: In a `groupby` `apply` passes dataframe slices.  A typical `apply` which you've used passes series for each row.  When accessing the dates within the series, you no longer need (it won't work) the `dt` accessor.

Comment: Oh... That's something I wouldn't have expected. I guess the way Timestamps are stored in Series differs from the way they are stored in DataFrame columns. Thanks for this piece of information... :)

Comment: `reset_index` is fastest over large datasets.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kartik! That was really useful. Although it solves the main problem here, I commented in piRSquared edit about the fact dt.month substraction is not a perfect substitute to my monthdelta() function in that it doesnt take into account years

Comment: What is the change you have made?

Comment: Was working on it. I did not know that numpy does not allow conversion from `'timedelta64[D]'` to `'timedelta64[M]'`. That stumped me for a few. I included a link to the reason in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.index.to_series().str.get(0)` to get at first level of index.

```
(df['Last Trade'].dt.month - df.index.to_series().str.get(0).dt.month) + \
(df['Last Trade'].dt.year - df.index.to_series().str.get(0).dt.year) * 12

Date        Ticker
1983-03-30  CLM83     2
            CLN83     3
            CLQ83     4
            CLU83     5
            CLV83     6
            CLX83     7
            CLZ83     8
1983-04-04  CLM83     1
            CLN83     2
            CLQ83     3
            CLU83     4
            CLV83     5
            CLX83     6
            CLZ83     7
dtype: int64
```

---

#### Timing

***Given `df`***

[image]

***`pd.concat([df for _ in range(10000)])`***

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `.reset_index` be faster than converting to Series, then using the string class?

Comment: @Kartik I'm checking.  But I wanted a clean way to preserve the index.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. `.reset_index` and extracting the month requires less computational steps than converting to Series, then using the str class to get the first level of index, and then extracting the month. `.apply` is just a loop, so would scale with increasing size, unlike direct subtraction... Awesome timing comparison!

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! This time analysis turns out to be really crucial to me since I am dealing with a very large database. I didn't know about dt accessors or even reset_index(), I had to look them up, These are really powerful tools.

Comment: I have just one problem remaining, both of you approaches don't take into account years, let's take an example: the difference between Jan15 and Dec14 will be -11 and I would like it to be 1

Comment: Is there a fast and efficient way to take that into account as well?

Comment: @MthClv That should do it.